# Adicionar duas escalas diferentes no ggplot

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber como faço para colocar duas escalas diferentes no plot do geom_line no R. Plotei duas linhas num mesmo gráfico, mas as escalas deles são diferentes, como faço para deixar duas escalas no eixo y? Uma para representar uma curva e a outra para representar a outra curva.
Segue o gráfico plotado:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então, eu já havia olhado este post antes, mas acredito que meu caso é diferente, devido os valores serem percentuais para ambas as curvas, mas um com uma escala menor e outro com uma escala maior. Por exemplo: PIB(-0.3,2.0) e Desemprego (11,15).

Answer (score 1):

Esta é uma alternativa e não uma resposta.

O ggplot tem por filosofia não implementar recursos que levam à visualizações ruins. É o caso de dois eixos Y para dados do mesmo tipo: é muito fácil se confundir na leitura dos dados.

Uma opção é ter gráficos individuais empilhados. Pode usar `facet_wrap` para isso, mas aqui está uma solução usando `ggpubr::ggarrange`, que na minha opinião possibilita controlar mais facilmente o *layout*:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

removeEixoX <- theme(axis.line.x = element_blank(),
                    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                    axis.ticks.x = element_blank() )

plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(1:nrow(mtcars), qsec)) +
  geom_line(colour = 'blue') +
  theme_minimal_hgrid() + removeEixoX

plot2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(1:nrow(mtcars), drat)) +
  geom_line(colour = 'darkred') +
  scale_y_continuous(position = 'right') +
  theme_minimal_hgrid() + removeEixoX

eixoX <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = 1:nrow(mtcars))) +
  theme_classic() + theme(axis.line.y = element_blank())

ggarrange(plot1, plot2, eixoX, ncol = 1, heights = c(5, 5, 1), align = 'v')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]